# react native KeyboardAvoidingView with already opened keyboard dont work properly

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-paper

In my App there are multiple situations where dialogs are shown. When a user should enter a Mail address and the format is wrong a react-native-paper Dialog will be opened inside a Portal.

```
<Portal>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={'padding'} style={{flex: 1}}>
     <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Dialog>
         [...]
```

When the Dialog appeared and afterwards the keyboard opens, everything moves up and it works fine! When the keyboard already is open and the Dialog appears, the dialog opens up behind the keyboard. Any Ideas how to fix?

I uploaded a video to show the behavior: https://streamable.com/zwin42

Already tried position and height as behavior as well, but it didnt work as well.

**This only happens on ios! Android works fine!**

Comment: You could call blur on TextInput after submit. That would hide the keyboard.

Comment: @MichaelBahl Thank you for your advice. I already tried `Keyboard.dismiss()` in onPress event of the button, but that does not feel great. Its more a work around than a solution.

Comment: Your streamable link does not open.

Comment: @Rohit It should open. I tried with different Devices and it works. May you check with another browser/device?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a workaround. The keyboard closing for a dialog is fairly normal

Comment: @BrandonDyer Thanks for answer. Problem is that I also track the internet connectivity by adding eventlistener to NetInfo `NetInfo.addEventListener`. So when the users keyboard is open and he loses internet connection a dialog will open behind the keyboard...

Comment: @YannickSchröder in that case, you could have it close they keyboard when the error is shown

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Try to use this lib instead:
https://github.com/kirillzyusko/react-native-keyboard-controller
It solved a lot of our problems.

---

This is what worked for us

1. We need to create a hook that will tell us that keyboard will hide (we will need it later):

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';

export const useKeyboardVisible = () => {
    const [isKeyboardWillHide, setKeyboardWillHide] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const keyboardWillHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', () => {
            setKeyboardWillHide(true);
        });

        return () => {
            keyboardWillHideListener.remove();
        };
    }, []);

    return { isKeyboardWillHide };
};
```

2. Next we will need to create a hook that will return us animated `marginBottom` styles (for smooth layout change):

- establish that keyboard is already visible using `Keyboard.isVisible();`;
- get keyboard height using `Keyboard.metrics()`;
- if keyboard is visible -> set `marginBottom` = `keyboard height`

```js
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import { useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withTiming } from 'react-native-reanimated';

const useKeyboardAlreadyVisibleMarginFix = () => {
    const { isKeyboardWillHide } = useKeyboardVisible();

    const marginBottom = useSharedValue(0);

    const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        return {
            marginBottom: marginBottom.value
                ? marginBottom.value
                : withTiming(0, {
                      duration: 300,
                  }),
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const isVisible = Keyboard.isVisible();
        const metrics = Keyboard.metrics();

        if (isVisible) {
            marginBottom.value = metrics?.height ?? 0;
        }

        if (isKeyboardWillHide) {
            marginBottom.value = 0;
        }

        return () => {
            marginBottom.value = 0;
        };
    }, [isKeyboardWillHide, marginBottom]);

    return { animatedStyle };
};
```

3. Use `Animated.View for making layout animation more user-friendly:

```js
import { Keyboard, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/elements';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';

// ...
 const height = useHeaderHeight();

 const { animatedStyle } = useKeyboardAlreadyVisibleMarginFix();

if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
   return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={{flex: 1}} keyboardVerticalOffset={height}>
         <Animated.View style={[{ flex: 1 }, animatedStyle]}>{children}</Animated.View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
   );
}
```